# Running two Magentos installations, one of which has 3 stores set up as multi-store. Which server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, sql-server, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I want to run 4 Magento stores in 2 different installations. 1 is a standalonne installation with 3 languages. The other is a multi-store with 3 different online stores in different domains.

At the moment we have a VPS with 1GB memory, would that be enough?

I ask because I've finished the standalone store and already put it online, and the server is already running on 62% memory. The ideal would be that this is enough as my company wouldn't like to move to a Dedicated Server (as it involves costs).

I'm sure I can try to optimize Magento to run on lower memory (I'm expecting visits averaging 2000/day on all sites), if I could have some tips on the best way to do that Id appreciate it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost definitely not. With 2k uniques a  day and the equivalent of 6 store views, you should be looking at a dedicated machine at a minimum. Have a look on page 2 here for a bit of guidance, and some sample configurations with estimated figures.

docs.sonassihosting.com/go_dedicated.pdf

If you want hard figures, your RAM usage would need to be something like this, you don't mention CPU cores, but I would guess 1 or 2

OS  -200MB

PHP - 120MB-3GB (4 threads at 30MB each, but with a Max memory/committed memory limit of 768MB per thread)

MySQL - 2GB (8 connections at around 50MB each, with buffers/cache/innodb pool of around 1.6GB minimum)

So your memory limit has been exceeded by a massive margin already. This is the key reason no-one should ever try to run Magento in a VPS, it is just too constrained an environment and usually with shared I/O. You could make it run in your VPS but you'd need aggressive caching or have to be content with it being very slow.

A good shared hosting package (from a proper, specialised Magento host) would outperform a similarly priced VPS by a significant margin and dedicated being the next step up.